# Hiding sub-folder from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, directory

First of all i would like to inform that this is my first post on stack overflow so if am i doing something wrong i would also like to let me know it.

I'm trying to build a PHP Script that includes folders like controller and templates. Both are redirecting and include-require php files on one or another within it. Everything is accessible through index on root domain directory. So my question is how can I hide from the url i.e. `domain.com/"controller"/activate.php` or `domain.com/"templates"/login.php`.

I'm letting you know that i call `login.php` inside "templates" folder through include within some parameters (`if`) in index.

I will now post my `.htaccess` so you can take a look about the process there, while i have already tried to hide "templates" folder in the past. But then the sub-directories were not accessible anymore by coding on .htaccess. That's why i had to remove codes were posted here, as those codes were not solution to my case.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    ErrorDocument 404 /templates/404

    # To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css         application/x-javascript application/javascript

Until now my .htaccess has parameters that hides .php extensions on url and cache-Gzip compression method. All help will appreciate it, wrong and correct!

Answer (score 0):

so if i am not wrong you got something like basepath/ControllerName/Method and you want to hide the ControllerName part? 
In my opinion, using MVC to play with url/friendlyurl and just keep a relatively basic htaccess like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smw/


# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can do what you want with a simple "routing" configuration :

For example :

a routing class to get the url and redirect

```
        public function __construct(){
    $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $uri = preg_replace("#".BASE_PATH_PATTERN."#i", "", $uri, 1);
    $this->uriExploded = explode("/",  trim($uri, "/")   );
     /*Check if there is another folder */
    $check = preg_match("/something/i", $uri);
    if($check != false)
    {
        /*instruction... */
    }
```

hope it is helping ! tell me if you need more info

Comment: It's not exactly what i mean. To help you more i 'm going to give you the details of folders and how it works. So:

Comment: Root domain directory httpd hosting:
`**assets** (folder that contains js, css, img, folders within)
**controller** (folder that contains php files with classes, functions, and db connections within them)
**languages** (folder that contains php files which checks the region and the decide which php file to read vocabulary-arrays)
**templates** (folder that contains php files such as login, activation and etc)
**.htaccess** (file that contains the specific code you saw above)
**index** (php file that include the login php file, which is locating inside templates folder)`

Comment: Let's hypothetically say we have index that calls login.php and profil.php (if the statement is true). So the url will shows up domain.com first and then if the statement is true will redirect into profil and url will change at domain.com/templates/profil.php. So i'm in middle of two methods on how to call and display the pages "correctly":

1) Use .htaccess somehow to take care and hide the subfolders.
2) Display everything on index, by using php files with functions and classes, on controller folder, that may include pages if the statements are correct and url be domain.com/something.php

Comment: any idea or solution? @younesdiouri

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for my afk moment;  so you don't want to display templates/profile.php you want to control and hide the template folder from the $url or the profile.php part ? @MihailLlaftiu

Comment: First of all there is no reason to ask for sorry. I am the one who should ask a sorry for posting so many things. The only think i can say is thank you and i appreciate your help. Second, exactly. I want to display in the url directly the php file name not the folder's name. So as i said before i 'm in middle of two methods, one by `.htaccess` and two by `statements` with `include`, displaying files only if there is correct. But what would you recommended (for being secured and fast)? @YounesDiouri

Comment: Thank you very much. Very glad to help !
Actually, in my opinion, I really  recommand to handle that with .htaccess rather than the include.
It's the logic way to handle the display, and as you said better loading (include everything on index could get a little tricky depending on your data). 
I'm wondering if you could get an eye on the Mvc handling technique because i'm always paying attention to my url's and since i'm using my own routes parameters I never had that kind of issue / dilemma for a long time. @MihailLlaftiu
Good luck !